# Powershell: Export-CSV and OutFile not doing what I expect

Tags: powershell, output, export-csv

Why am I getting a blank file here? When I run it before the export-csv I get PLENTY of records all showing up in the console.

[image: output]

So here's the code I'm using

```
$path = "C:\test"

Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Include *.edi, *.x12, *.filename, *.dat, *.log, *.mdn, *.req -Recurse -Force |
Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer -and ((get-date)-$_.LastWriteTime).days -gt 30 } |
Remove-Item -force -whatif | export-csv D:\output.csv #also I try out-file D:\output.txt
```

Comment: Pretty sure -Whatif generates Verbose output so there wouldn't be any objects in the pipeline to pass to Export-csv.

Comment: @EBGreen: Good point about `-WhatIf` in general, but it looks like the information is printed straight to the console, not to the verbose output stream (number `4`).

Comment: @mklement0 You are correct in that assumption (it's a `[string]` object output to the `1` stream)

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: In the context of PowerShell, `1` is the success (data) output stream, but this is not where `-WhatIf` output goes - as far as I can tell, you cannot capture / redirect it all from _within_ PowerShell. (You could from the outside, such as when calling from `cmd.exe`).

Comment: @mklement0 Hmm, I was quick to jump the gun here.  Wrapping a command in parens and accessing its type reported string, but now attempting to use redirection or other cmdlets doesn't capture that output.  It doesn't even use `5` (Information) like `Write-Host` does in PSv5

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1: I'm curious: what specific command reported string as the output type with `-WhatIf`?

Comment: @mklement0 `(New-Item -Path 'C:\path' -WhatIf).GetType()` ah wait- I used `out-string` on a null ref.  I feel dumb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Common parameter **`-WhatIf`** - used for *previewing* a command's actions - never outputs *data*; instead, the **preview information is printed *straight to the console*, meaning it can neither be sent through the pipeline, nor redirected to file, nor captured**.

<sup>As an aside: `Remove-Item` *without* `-WhatIf` also never produces data output, so there is generally no point in trying to process its output in a subsequent pipeline segment.</sup>

Your best bet is to **add an `-OutVariable` (`-ov`) common parameter to your `Where-Object` call**, which allows you to export the collected file-info objects via `Export-Csv` in a *separate* command:

```
Get-ChildItem ... | Where-Object -OutVariable filesToRemove { ... } | 
  Remove-Item -WhatIf ...
$filesToRemove | Export-Csv D:\output.csv
```

The above still prints the preview information to the console, but also collects the `[System.IO.FileInfo]` objects selected by `Where-Object` in variable `$filesToRemove`, which you can then export in CSV format.